# How do I disable "simplify chained comparison" in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, lint, intellij-inspections

I understand that a statement like

```
if x > y and y > z:
   pass
```

can be simplified to

```
if x > y > z:
   pass
```

but honestly I prefer to have the first one, don't judge me please. Is there a way to disable this option in PyCharm, or maybe a way to not get that warning anymore?

Comment: What are you trying to disable, a lint or a formatting option?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to `Editor` > `Inspections` in settings, and under "Python" uncheck the option "Too complex chained comparisons".

The description for this inspection is as follows.

> Reports chained comparisons that can be simplified.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
>  def do_comparison(x):
>      xmin = 10
>      xmax = 100
>      if x >= xmin and x <= xmax:
>          pass
> ```
>
> The IDE offers to simplify `if x >= xmin and x <= xmax`. When the quick-fix is applied, the code changes to:
>
> ```
>  def do_comparison(x):
>      xmin = 10
>      xmax = 100
>      if xmin <= x <= xmax:
>          pass
> ```

Comment: Thank you! It's really just matter of preference, thanks a lot :)